# GridView TemplateItem Width

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a `GridView` which contains a `TemplateItem` column which contains a textbox.  The grid itself works fine, the rows are create, I can edit the text box, etc.  But the width is static.  I can manually set the width but ideally I'd like it to just automatically stretch to whatever size the column is.

I've tried Googling an answer to this, and everything I've seen has been around using CSS or having a Width property assign a specific width.

This is my GridView code:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdSelectedProducts" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="grdSelectedProducts_OnRowDataBound" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Product" HeaderText="Product" ReadOnly="False" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
            <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDescription" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `width:auto`, Though you may not see a `style` property for a `<asp:TextBox>` still it will render it

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDescription" style="width:auto !important" 
     Text="">
```

Comment: hello, it still appears as the same size.

Comment: @MattR, check the td column width you set. It may prevent

Comment: I'm not sure I follow?  I don't have any <td> fields?

Comment: I ended up having to set the width to 98% and not auto, but your answer gave me the starting point.  Many thanks.